# Download Images stored in Azure Blob Storage as Images using C#

Tags: azure

I have stored a bunch of images in Azure Blob Storage. Now I want to retrieve them & resize them.
I have successfully managed to read much information from the account, such as the filename, the date last modified, and the size, but how do I get the actual image? Examples I have seen show me how to download it to a file, but that is no use to me, I want to download it as an image so I can process it.

This is what I have so far:

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");

        // build table to hold the info
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("blobItemName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("blobItemLastModified", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("blobItemSizeKB", typeof(double));
        table.Columns.Add("blobImage", typeof(Image));

        // row counter for table
        int intRowNo = 0;
        // divider to convert Bytes to KB
        double dblBytesToKB = 1024.00;
        // List all blobs in the container
        await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
        {
            // increment row number
            intRowNo++;
            //Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            // length in bytes
            long? longContentLength = blobItem.Properties.ContentLength;
            double dblKb = 0;
            if (longContentLength.HasValue == true)
            {
                long longContentLengthValue = longContentLength.Value;
                // convert to double DataType
                double dblContentLength = Convert.ToDouble(longContentLengthValue);
                // Convert to KB
                dblKb = dblContentLength / dblBytesToKB;
            }
            // get the image
            
            // **** Image thisImage = what goes here ?? actual data from blobItem ****

            // Last modified date
            string date = blobItem.Properties.LastModified.ToString();
            try
            {
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
                //Console.WriteLine("The specified date is valid: " + dateTime);
                table.Rows.Add(intRowNo, blobItem.Name, dateTime, dblKb);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse the specified date");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a read stream for your image, and construct your .NET `Image` from this stream:

```
await foreach (BlobItem item in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync()){
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(item.Name);
    using Stream stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();
    Image myImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
    //...
}
```

The [blobclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) class also exposes some other helpful methods, like a download to a stream.